# google analytics tracking button

Tags: html, button, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tracking

hello I have my web page: https://arab-exchanges.org/conference/
I am trying to track button " Download Agenda". all button I tracked already.
how to track this button?
thank you

Comment: Have you tried tracking by link text in your triggers in tag manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
<script>
var getOutboundLink = function(url) {
  gtag('event', 'click', {
    'event_category': 'download agenda',
    'event_label': 'https://arab-exchanges.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/AFE-SAUDI-2021-Agenda-1.pdf'
  });
}
</script>

<a href="https://arab-exchanges.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/AFE-SAUDI-2021-Agenda-1.pdf" onclick="getOutboundLink('https://arab-exchanges.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/AFE-SAUDI-2021-Agenda-1.pdf'); return false;" target="_blank" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-sm" role="button"><span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper"><span class="elementor-button-text">Download Agenda</span></span></a>
```

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7478520?hl=en